# SQL Server 2000 Replication, Performance, and Query Priorities

Tags: sql-server, performance, replication

I'm a developer and wanting to confirm the following:

Does anyone here have experience with SQL Server Replication (transactional) on 2000? We are trying to convince the DBAs to allow this in a production environment so that we can concurrently run "tests" -- but the DBAs are telling us that Replication in SQL Server 2000 doesn't work and/or that it has a severe performance impact on the source server.

I tried googling some information on this but haven't found any such information.

Also, do you know if it is true/not true that queries from Stored Procedures or queries called from a Linked Servers will take precedence over other queries (e.g. dynamic queries from a connecting application). I didn't think this was possible and have found no reference to this via my google searches... but the DBA claims this is true for SQL Server 2000, and as a result, causes notable performance slowdown from users of the web app connecting to the database.

Thanks!

Comment: For context, I believe this is an offshoot of this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293757/best-way-to-perform-distributed-sql-query-and-joins-calling-from-net-code)

Comment: yes billinkc, that is my question on SO looking for options. My question here is really to confirm what I've been told by our DBAs. Thanks.

Comment: My first question would be... Why would you want to use an usupported version of SQL Server. SQL Server 2000 has already reached EOL as you can see here: http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that **[You are arguing for an UNSUPPORTED version of sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/end-of-extended-lifecycle-support-for-sql-server-2000-service-pack-4)**.

Apart from that read below :

> but the DBAs are telling us that Replication in SQL Server 2000 doesn't work and/or that it has a severe performance impact on the source server.

This is completely **False**. Why would T-Rep not work in sql 2000 ? Why would it have a severe performance impact on source server ?

The only impact that I can see is

- During the initial snapshot generation as it **locks** the table while the snapshot is generated and if the table is **huge** then it will lock it for longer durations. Imagine this causing blocking or possibly timeouts.
- when you are replicating the entire database (not only required set of tables/articles) and when you want to reinitialize the replicaiton - meaning new snapshot !
- When the n/w bandwithd is not good or there are n/w related issues.

Above holds true even today for sql server 2012 or 2014.

Note that T-Rep on sql 2005 and up has improved a lot, but the argument your DBA has made is baseless. **We even has some legacy applications running on sql 2000 and we use replication heavily and is stable in sql 2000 - no issues at all**.

> if it is true/not true that queries from Stored Procedures or queries called from a Linked Servers will take precedence over other queries (e.g. dynamic queries from a connecting application).

Again completely **baseless** or you might have misunderstood it. Stored procedures can have their plan complied and stored in procedure cache and the plan can be reused.

I don't think you can have priority of the kind you have mentioned.

Comment: thank you - that's what I thought too. And in no way am I advocating for the continued use of SQL Server 2000. This database is used by an installed version of an old PeopleSoft for a government organization with over 40K employees. It is not a trivial task to upgrade (so I'm told)... so I have to work with what I'm given.